# Why can't I send `None` as data in a POST request using Python's `requests` library?

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

It seems that when a key in `data` has a value of `None`, the key isn't included by requests.

```
>>> req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://google.com', data=dict(a=None, b=1))
>>> req.prepare().body
'b=1'
```

Why is this the case? I was expecting an empty string, or something like `json.dumps(d)` where `None` is rendered as `null`. I'm sure there's a good reason -- just curious about what it is. (One thing I can think of is that maybe there just isn't an encoding of `null` or `None` available to the POST request -- is that true?)

Additionally curious -- why does `requests` silently ignore such data instead of throwing an error?

Comment: `None` is a special class (python3.x) / type (python2.x) that's intentionally designed to denote the absence of a value. If you want an empty string, make `a` an empty string (`a=""`). More info  [here](http://pythoncentral.io/python-null-equivalent-none/#custom-tab-0-python-2-x)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting a dictionary element to `None` is how you explicitly say that you don't want that parameter to be sent to the server.

I can't find this mentioned specifically in the `requests.Request()` documentation, but in [Passing Parameters in URLs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) it says:

> Note that any dictionary key whose value is None will not be added to the URL's query string.

Obviously it uses consistent logic for `POST` requests as well.

If you want to send an empty string, set the dictionary element to an empty string rather than `None`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What I'm wondering now is why `requests` provides this facility for ignoring parameters. If I don't want it to be sent, can't I just not include it in the dict?

Comment: @EliRose this is provided because you might have defaults set on a session that you don't want sent. Since the flow you're using ignores that, you can always just manually update the body to be what you expect.

Comment: @sigmavirus24: Interesting -- could you possibly point me to an example of the use case you're talking about? re: the alternative you mention; in real life I'm just using `request.post(...)`, the `req.prepare().body` is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: @EliRose They probably all use a common routine to process the data dictionary, and `None` is the placeholder used to remove parameters.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with a blank value and this was my workaround. I sent the data as json string and set content type headers as application/json. This seems to send the whole data across as expected. Took quite some time to figure out. Hope this helps someone.

```
import requests
import json

header = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

data = {
    "xxx": None,
    "yyy": "http://",
    "zzz": 12345
    }

res = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', 
                    data=json.dumps(data), headers=header)

obj = json.loads(res.text)

print obj['json']
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question few days ago and if you replace data with json it should work for you, as now `None` will be sent in the body.

```
request('POST', 'http://google.com', json=dict(a=None, b=1))
```