# Python requests.put, how to set key to null

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Does anyone know how to send `None` with `requests`? As I understand that by having `None` will make Python ignore `'port_id'` and that it will not be included in the body.

Is there a way to change that and make sure `None` is sent?

```
 data = {'port_id': None,
         'token': TOKEN}

 r = requests.put(URL + 'api/port/'+ str('id') + '', data=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried building the appropriate JSON string yourself? With only two keys, it should be straightforward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I send \`None\` as data in a POST request using Python's \`requests\` library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271697/why-cant-i-send-none-as-data-in-a-post-request-using-pythons-requests-libr)