# How to encode None in dost data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my django app, X is a nullable decimalField. I am getting this error because the value of X is Null in few scenarios. How can I handle this in situations where it Null?

```
    def my_serialization(self):
        return {
            'id': self.app.id,
            ‘name’: self.app.name,
            ‘X’: self.app.x
        }

    def my_test(self):
        payload = self.my_serialization
        response = self.client.post(url, payload)
```

This gives my an error:

> ‘Cannot encode None as POST data. Did you mean to pass an '
>   TypeError: Cannot encode None as POST data. Did you mean to pass an empty string or omit the value?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271843/9279181

Comment: @GauravAgarwal My scenario involves the Key x to be Null. I cannot omit sending it in the post request and I can neither replace None with an empty string because x is a decimalFeild. Is there any other solution that I am missing?

Comment: I fixed this by explicitly sending x only if it is a decimal. I had to omit sending x in m test fixtures altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by omitting 'X' from my_serialization when X is null and sending x only if it is a decimal.

```
def my_serialization(self):
    if self.app.X == None:
        return {
            'id': self.app.id,
            'name': self.app.name
        }
    else:
        return {
            'id': self.app.id,
            ‘name’: self.app.name,
            'X': set_x(self.app.x)
        }

def my_test(self):
    payload = self.my_serialization
    response = self.client.post(url, payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how well this would work but can you try this?

```
def set_x(x):
    if x == None:
        return ''
    else:
        return x

def my_serialization(self):
    return {
        'id': self.app.id,
        'name': self.app.name,
        'X': set_x(self.app.x)
    }

def my_test(self):
    payload = self.my_serialization
    response = self.client.post(url, payload)
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need x to be either Null or a decimal value. I can't change it to an empty string

Comment: There is no Null or None in REST post requests. You post requests gets converted into a stream of bytes and sending an empty string is the same as sending a Null. Try this. It will work (if that's the only concern with this solution)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tweaked it a bit for the desired outcome.

Comment: Glad it worked. I assumed that the presence of the key was important in the request body.